# Insert rows with null values to HBase with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

Trying to write a Spark dataframe with `null` column values, I am getting exception about `unsupported data type`.
There is a sample of code:

```
val sql = spark.sqlContext 

case class Person(name: String, email: String, height: Float) 

var personDS = Seq(Person("alice", "alice@alice.com", 4.5f),Person("bob", null, 5.1f) ).toDS 
//                                                                        ----
//                                                                          ^ null value

personDS.write.format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark").option("hbase.columns.mapping", "name STRING :key, email STRING c:email, height FLOAT p:height").option("hbase.table", "test").option("hbase.spark.use.hbasecontext", false).option("spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs", false).save()
```

The exception is

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$11.apply(Executor.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1408)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:413)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: unsupported data type StringType
        at org.apache.spark.sql.datasources.hbase.Utils$.toBytes(Utils.scala:87)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.HBaseRelation$$anonfun$org$apache$hadoop$hbase$spark$HBaseRelation$$convertToPut$1$2.apply(DefaultSource.scala:225)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.HBaseRelation$$anonfun$org$apache$hadoop$hbase$spark$HBaseRelation$$convertToPut$1$2.apply(DefaultSource.scala:224)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.HBaseRelation.org$apache$hadoop$hbase$spark$HBaseRelation$$convertToPut$1(DefaultSource.scala:224)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.HBaseRelation$$anonfun$insert$1.apply(DefaultSource.scala:231)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.HBaseRelation$$anonfun$insert$1.apply(DefaultSource.scala:231)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:129)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1442)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:139)
        ... 10 more
```

Of course, I can separate `Person`s with null values like the following:

```
case class Person(name: String, email: String, height: Float) 
case class Person_without_email(name: String, height: Float) 

var personDS = Seq(Person("alice", "alice@alice.com", 4.5f)).toDS 
var person_without_email_DS = Seq(Person(Person_without_email("bob", 5.1f) )).toDS 

personDS.write.format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark").option("hbase.columns.mapping", "name STRING :key, email STRING c:email, height FLOAT p:height").option("hbase.table", "test").option("hbase.spark.use.hbasecontext", false).option("spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs", false).save()    
person_without_email_DS.write.format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark").option("hbase.columns.mapping", "name STRING :key, height FLOAT p:height").option("hbase.table", "test").option("hbase.spark.use.hbasecontext", false).option("spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs", false).save()
```

This approach looks ugly. I should split original dataframe on large number of parts (~ !(number of fields)). Is there more convenient way to process rows with null values?

---

HBase 2.1.0-cdh6.2.1 
Spark 2.4.0-cdh6.2.1

Comment: What versions of Spark and HBase are you using?

Comment: Splitting the original dataframe in a dataframe containing all rows and all non nullable fields, and a dataframe per nullable field A containing the rows having non null values for A, should do it.

Comment: @ArthurPICHOTUTRERA -  HBase 2.1.0-cdh6.2.1
Spark 2.4.0-cdh6.2.1

Comment: Seems like https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-21841. The fix implemented there by the way is to NOT attempt to write null cells into HBase at all. So only workaround, if you still want to see all dataframe columns populated in a table, would be to replace all null values in it with empty strings `""`.